# Error while trying to sort in T-SQL by declaring the data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

I am trying to learn T-SQL programming and I noticed my below code has an error. This code is for learning how to sort without order by and it looks like bubble sort algorithms.

I first create the table and insert random numbers after I tried to do the sorting

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #NumbersArray
(
    ArrayIndex INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Value INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO #NumbersArray(ArrayIndex, Value)
    SELECT 0, 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 3 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 2

SELECT * FROM #NumbersArray
GO    

DECLARE @CurrentIndex INT,
        @MaxIndex INT,
        @swapoccured BIT

SET @swapoccured = 1
SET @MaxIndex = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM #NumbersArray)

WHILE (@swapoccured = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @swapoccured = 0
    SET @CurrentIndex = 0

    WHILE (@CurrentIndex < @MaxIndex)
        DECLARE @value1 INT
        DECLARE @value2 INT
    BEGIN  -- Mistake was here. I put the begin in wrong place
        SET @value1 = (SELECT Value FROM #NumbersArray WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex)
        SET @value2 = (SELECT Value FROM #NumbersArray WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex + 1)

        IF (@value1 > @value2)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #NumbersArray 
            SET Value = @value2 
            WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex

            UPDATE #NumbersArray 
            SET Value = @value1 
            WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex + 1

            SET @swapoccured = 1
         END

         SET @CurrentIndex = @CurrentIndex + 1
    END
END

SELECT * FROM #NumbersArray
```

So I think my code stock in middle of sorting in second while since my while never finish but I can determine what is the issue.

Comment: This bubble sort implementation looks incorrect. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @SalmanA I have wrote it :) I did not get it from any where but I have fixed the code and I attached it to the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ordering data is impossible without `ORDER BY` clause (read @ZoharPeled's answer), so this is not the appropriate approach. That's way I'll focus only on your error. The reason is the second `WHILE` loop. Without `BEGIN .. END` this loop just declares one variable endlessly: `WHILE (@CurrentIndex < @MaxIndex) DECLARE @value1 INT`.

This is probably what you want (use this just to learn how to use `WHILE` loops, not how to order data):

```
CREATE TABLE #NumbersArray
(
    ArrayIndex INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Value INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO #NumbersArray(ArrayIndex, Value)
    SELECT 0, 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 3 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 2

SELECT * FROM #NumbersArray
GO    

DECLARE @CurrentIndex INT,
        @MaxIndex INT,
        @swapoccured BIT

SET @swapoccured = 1
SET @MaxIndex = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM #NumbersArray)

WHILE (@swapoccured = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @swapoccured = 0
    SET @CurrentIndex = 0

    DECLARE @value1 INT
    DECLARE @value2 INT
    WHILE (@CurrentIndex < @MaxIndex)
    BEGIN
        SET @value1 = (SELECT Value FROM #NumbersArray WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex)
        SET @value2 = (SELECT Value FROM #NumbersArray WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex + 1)

        IF (@value1 > @value2)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #NumbersArray 
            SET Value = @value2 
            WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex

            UPDATE #NumbersArray 
            SET Value = @value1 
            WHERE ArrayIndex = @CurrentIndex + 1

            SET @swapoccured = 1
         END

         SET @CurrentIndex = @CurrentIndex + 1
    END
END

SELECT * FROM #NumbersArray

DROP TABLE #NumbersArray
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations. I actually have started to learn the coding and I believed that I have to be able to code anything with TSQL without using optional clauses(such as Order By and Group By). So I have started to see if I can code something without using order by. I am completyl agree that my code is not useful since we have order by. It is look like you use harder way to retrieve specific row of data without using OFFSET and Fetch. I am only learning this way to answer interview questions by SQL programming instead of C or Python programming.

Comment: I was thinking that I am a little bit more comfortable with SQL syntaxes :) Thank you soo soo much for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

> This code is for learning how to sort without order by...

Well, that's simply impossible to do.
In a relational database, the tables are unsorted by nature. The only way to ensure the order of the results returned from a query is by using the `order by` clause.

> I am trying to learn T-SQL programming

The first thing to learn about any dialect of SQL is that it is designed to work with a set based approach - meaning operations are done on sets of rows, rather then with a procedural based approach (A.K.A [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) - Raw by agonizing raw).
You can search 'set based vs procedural' and come up with many articles explaining in details the difference between these approaches.

So, having said that - using loops (and nested loops even more) is discouraged in the SQL world - that includes cursors, while loops and even recursive common table expressions.
Most of the times, you can avoid using loops by using a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) - changing the RBAR approach with a set based approach and making your code that much more efficient and most of the time easier to write, read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations. I actually have started to learn the coding and I believed that I have to be able to code anything with TSQL without using optional clauses(such as Order By and Group By). So I have started to see if I can code something without using order by. I am completyl agree that my code is not useful since we have order by. It is look like you use harder way to retrieve specific row of data without using OFFSET and Fetch. I am only learning this way to answer interview questions by SQL programming instead of C or Python programming.

Comment: I was thinking that I am a little bit more comfortable with SQL syntaxes  :) Thank you soo soo much for your time :)